# R (quantmod), plot own indicator, Error in seq.default

Tags: r, xts, quantmod, indicator

I want to plot my own simple indicator in quantmod like so:

```
own.ind <- as.matrix(c(1,2,3), ncol=1, nrow=3)
rownames(own.ind) <- c("2017-01-23", "2017-01-24", "2017-01-25")
own.ind <- as.xts(own.ind)
getSymbols("AAPL", from = as.Date("2017-01-23"), to = as.Date("2017-01-25"))
chartSeries(AAPL)
addTA(own.ind)
```

But it earned me an error saying

```
Error in seq.default(min(tav * 0.975, na.rm = TRUE), max(tav * 1.05, na.rm = TRUE),  : 
'from' cannot be NA, NaN or infinite
```

and two additional warnings:

```
1: In min(tav * 0.975, na.rm = TRUE) :  no non-missing arguments to min; returning Inf
2: In max(tav * 1.05, na.rm = TRUE) :  no non-missing arguments to max; returning -Inf
```

What's wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Joe, you have to create a function to add the series as indicator. To create an indicator which adds 1 per trading day as in your example do the following:

```
myInd <- function(x) {
  x <- 1:NROW(x)
  return(x)
}
```

create the new indicator:

```
addMyInd <- newTA(FUN = myInd, legend = "MyInd")
```

to check `class`:

```
> class(addMyInd)
[1] “function”
```

Now let’s chart the new indicator below the price chart:

```
getSymbols("AAPL", from = "2017-01-23", to = "2017-01-25")
chartSeries(AAPL,TA=NULL)
addMyInd()
```

[image]

Comment: hvollmeier... don't have any info for contacting you, but wanted to tell you i believe there's a bug slipped into your VXX dropbox feed that's listed on several blog sites.  currently, there's a 4x drop in prices in your feed starting aug 4 2014 and prior dates that looks odd and is not reflected in other feeds (like yahoo historical).  actually, i'm only guessing that you are that hvollmeier, if not please ignore this :-)  sorry in advance for being so off topic here  :-(

Comment: Bingo, @hvollmeier.  Thanks for the fix, and for the welcome data.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that the index for your `own.ind` object does not align with any of the index values in the `AAPL` object.  This is because `as.xts` converts the rownames of your matrix to `POSIXct` by default.  `POSIXct` objects have a timezone, and `Date` objects don't have a timezone.

```
R> merge(Cl(AAPL), own.ind)
           AAPL.Close own.ind
2017-01-23     120.08      NA
2017-01-23         NA       1
2017-01-24     119.97      NA
2017-01-24         NA       2
2017-01-25     121.88      NA
2017-01-25         NA       3
```

So you either need to specify the `dateFormat` argument to `as.xts` or use the `xts` constructor and `as.Date` directly.

```
# use dateFormat
own.ind <- as.matrix(c(1,2,3), ncol=1, nrow=3)
rownames(own.ind) <- c("2017-01-23", "2017-01-24", "2017-01-25")
own.ind <- as.xts(own.ind, dateFormat = "Date")
merge(Cl(AAPL), own.ind)
#            AAPL.Close own.ind
# 2017-01-23     120.08       1
# 2017-01-24     119.97       2
# 2017-01-25     121.88       3

# use xts constructor and as.Date
own.ind <- xts(1:3, as.Date(c("2017-01-23", "2017-01-24", "2017-01-25")))
merge(Cl(AAPL), own.ind)
#            AAPL.Close own.ind
# 2017-01-23     120.08       1
# 2017-01-24     119.97       2
# 2017-01-25     121.88       3
```

Now you can use `addTA` without having to create a function as the other answer says you must.

```
chartSeries(AAPL, TA="addTA(own.ind)")
```

[image]

Comment: This simplifies matters considerably. Thanks a lot!